# Pointwise mutual information for tag generation in Twitter

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

I came across the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764116/tag-generation-from-a-small-text-content-such-as-tweets

The question is about how do we assign tag to tweets automatically, the answer suggest using pointwise mutual information, however, my question is if how can we achieve it?

If we have 1000 unique tweets and 100 unique tags, the probability of hashtag $x$ appear in tweet $y$ $p(x,y) = 1$, $p(x) = 1/1000$ and $p(y) = 1/1000$ will always stay, right?

Can someone please enlighten me on this please?

Comment: If you have 1000 tags and only 1 data point per each, you don't really have enough data to do anything with it...